# Setting HTTP cache control headers in WCF service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest, http-caching

I'm working on an HTTP REST service implemented on WCF. I'd like to set the HTTP cache control headers for my operations appropriately.

I've seen a few examples that involve using the `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse` to modify the headers in each method. But let's be honest, that's a pain in the butt, especially since nearly all of my operations are going to use the same cache control policy (no-cache).

I'm thinking there must be an elegant way to set this. Perhaps a combination of a ServiceBehavior to set a service-level default, and OperationBehaviors to override that for certain operations? Or maybe there's some better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF services respect the [outputCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) setting in the Web.Config.  Additionally you can specify  [OutputCacheProfiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.outputcacheprofile%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which are also defined in the Web.config and then [specify which OutputCacheProfle to use at the method level with decorators](http://weblogs.asp.net/gsusx/archive/2008/10/29/adding-caching-to-wcf-restful-services-using-the-rest-starter-kit.aspx).

Comment: I haven't tried this, but my understanding of Output Caching is that it only related to keeping results in memory, and doesn't affect the HTTP cache control headers.

Comment: @BrianReischl OutputCacheProfiles have a location attribute that can be defined as Server or Client.  When set to Client a response contains HTTP Headers matching the OutputCacheProfile's definition.